How to perform AWS S3 replication using LocalStack?
I have AWS setup to replicate put objects from one bucket to another.
Now I am planning to test this using LocalStack as a testing tool.
Following is my code
awslocal --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 s3 mb s3://bucket-1
awslocal s3api put-bucket-versioning --bucket bucket-1 --versioning-configuration Status=Enabled
awslocal --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 s3 mb s3://bucket-2
awslocal s3api put-bucket-versioning --bucket bucket-2 --versioning-configuration Status=Enabled
awslocal s3api put-bucket-replication --bucket bucket-1 --replication-configuration '{"Role": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/replication-role","Rules": [{"Status": "Enabled","Priority": 1,"DeleteMarkerReplication": {"Status": "Disabled"},"Destination": {"Bucket": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-2”,”AccessControlTranslation": {"Owner": "Destination"}}}]}'
awslocal s3api get-bucket-replication --bucket bucket-1 

awslocal s3api get-bucket-replication --bucket bucket-1 gives below output.
{
    "ReplicationConfiguration": {
        "Role": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/replication-role",
        "Rules": [
            {
                "ID": "DC787334”,
                "Priority": 1,
                "Status": "Enabled",
                "Destination": {
                    "Bucket": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-2,
                    "AccessControlTranslation": {
                        "Owner": "Destination"
                    }
                },
                "DeleteMarkerReplication": {
                    "Status": "Disabled"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

But no objects are being replicated to the bucket-2.
Any idea why is this happening ?

S3 Bucket Replication is not yet emulated in LocalStack, here's the open feature request in the GitHub repository: https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/10759
It's currently only mocked, and the replication is not taking place.

Ok I might need to find workaround for this until they release the feature.
Thank you.
